# The rank of QR factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

If A is a $m\times n$ matrix $m\geq n$,A=QR is a reduced QR factorization. If R has k nonzero diagonal entries ($0\leq k<n$). I want to know what is the rank of A.Is it at least k?

Comment: There seems to be a typo -- you probably want to know the rank of something other than $k$?

Answer (score 2):

$A=QR=[Q_1,Q_2]\begin{bmatrix}R_1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=Q_1R_1$

Since $Q_1$ has full column rank, so $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(Q_1R_1)=\operatorname{rank}(R_1)=k$.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_factorization#Rectangular_matrix) for more info.